# Send raspberryPi data into google cloud storage

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a project that there is a raspberry pi that generates some data as CSV files in a laptop connected to it. My goal is to send these CSV files regularly into GCS (real-time or each 15minutes).
Then I will be using google cloud functions to send the data from GCS to BigQuery.
The raspberry pi is registered in the network (I am not sure how it can help)

**My question:** *How do send CSV files from the laptop connected to raspberry Pi into Google cloud storage buckets?*

Comment: Its not clear how the laptop and the PI related to each other.  Which of the machines will have the CSV data to sent to GCS?  Where do you want to send the data from ... the laptop or the Pi?  What programming language are you using?

At the highest level, there are "client libraries" that you can code to which can connect to GCP and create new objects (files) in a GCS bucket that contain the content you wish to upload.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the GCS client libraries:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries

The one from python may be your best fit for the raspberry https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/

You will need a GCP project, create a bucket and create a ServiceAccount with permission to upload files. Download the ServiceAccount file to your raspeberry and use it as specified in the Client Library you chose: basically specify the credentials file location in your script or as a env var.

BTW to insert the file into BigQuery you could use the Cloud Storage pubsub notifications that create messages when new files are uploaded, then with a Push subscription to your Cloud Function may load it into the BigQuery with the BigQuery Client Library. Take a look to: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications?hl=es-419